# Cannot use proportional sizing when creating video thumbnails with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have the following command to create a thumbnail image every ten seconds from a video file (note the fixed width and height).

```
ffmpeg -i c:\FFMPEGTest\myVideo.MTS -vf fps=1/10 -s 320:180 c:\FFMPEGTest\myThumbs%03d.jpg
```

I am trying to use the proportional sizing like so (as per examples available on various sites I have looked at);

```
ffmpeg -i c:\FFMPEGTest\myVideo.MTS -vf fps=1/10 -s 320:-1 c:\FFMPEGTest\myThumbs%03d.jpg
```

However, the above code fails with an "invalid frame size" error. I have tried surrounding the scale/size with quotes, back-ticks etc, but I either get an "invalid argument" error or an "invalid frame size" error.

This worked, but it outputs every frame and seems to ignore the fps=1/10 option (one frame for every ten seconds)

```
ffmpeg -i c:\FFMPEGTest\myVideo.MTS -vf fps=1/10 -filter:v scale="280:-1" c:\FFMPEGTest\myThumbs%03d.jpg
```

(is the -vf a duplication of the -filter:v option?) EDIT: After reading the documentation on the FFMPEG site, apparently -vf and -filter:v are aliases of one another - I tried removing one and then the other and still have the same errors.

All I am looking for is a way to have the proportional sizing work with the first command above, which works perfectly well (proportional sizing aside).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to capture 1/10 frame without scaling?

Once you fixed that you can work on scaling.

Comment: Yes, the first command shown in my question works perfectly fine with fixed scaling sizes in place, it just fails as soon as I try to proportionally scale using the 320:-1 sizing. Further to that, I have tried moving the order of the options around, to no avail. It also works fine if I remove the sizing altogether.

Comment: and instead of -1 use a number like 320:180. It may not understand -1 as auto size.

Comment: The first command I used (which works) is this one, note the actual numbers.

    ffmpeg -i c:\FFMPEGTest\myVideo.MTS -vf fps=1/10 -s 320:180 c:\FFMPEGTest\myThumbs%03d.jpg

The documentation says you can use the "-1" as a "resize proportionally" flag. But it seems not to be working. I have tried with quotes, without quotes, back-ticks etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after a lot of messing around with some other examples I found, here's what works for me.

```
ffmpeg -i c:\FFMPEGTest\myVideo.MTS -filter:v "fps=fps=1/10,scale=w=320:h=ih*(320/iw)" c:\FFMPEGTest\myThumbs%03d.jpg
```

Not the nicest command to look at, but it works. And no, the fps=fps=1/10 is not a typo. Yuck.

Comment: `-vf "fps=1/10,scale=320:-1"`

Comment: Thanks Mulvya, I realised that my syntax was not correct in some uses - I did not realise that you had to call the -vf modifier once for each parameter you wanted to set, or group them together within quotes.

Comment: All video filters HAVE to be grouped together. With multiple calls for the same output, only the last one takes effect.

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya. It would seem that several of the examples I was looking at around the internet were wrong in that case. No wonder I was having issues. :)